# how to play a pre-recorded sound in speaker or mic during a call..?

Tags: android, android-service

Is this possible to play a pre-recorded sound in speaker or mic during a call.. so that other party could hear it?

Comment: kindly share your solution..

Comment: plz share your answer.

Comment: hey you able to play a recorded sound in speaker or mic during a call..?i have to done the same .if u done then please help me .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171966/is-it-possible-in-android-to-record-the-call-during-incoming-or-outgoing-calls/9172205#9172205) first before reading through. The modem processor directly feeds from the mic and since there is not wiring between the app and modem processor, IMHO you cannot route the pre-recorded audio to the other end.

The other party can hear only what the microphone picks up. So, if you play a pre-recorded audio file while in a call on the speaker, and it is loud enough, the mic will pick up the audio and it will be heard at the other end. Not sure if echo cancellation will have an "adverse" effect in this case by eliminating the audio from the speaker.

Comment: Thanks! It means I must play the audio in loudspeaker to make the caller hear per-recorded sound. And also that while on call IT IS POSSIBLE to play pre-recorded sound with MediaPlayer! am i right??

Comment: hey you able to  play a recorded sound in speaker or mic during a call..?i have to done the same .if u done then please help me .